# What are the arguments for and against extending native prototypes?

Tags: javascript, prototype, nodelist

I was wondering what the cleanest way is in vanilla DOM to set a property on every element in a NodeList (Kind of how jQuery applies its `.attr,.prop,.css,.data` calls on every element in the jQuery object.)

And that got me thinking, what would the arguments be against extending the NodeList prototype with something like a `setAll` function?

Take this short example (And excuse its crude nature, as its a quick example)

```
NodeList.prototype.setAll = function(k, v){
  var keys = k.split('.');
  var last = keys.pop();
  for(var e of this){
    var o = e;
    keys.forEach(k=>{
      o = o[k];
    });
    o[last] = v;
  }
}
```

Then you could make statements like

`querySelectorAll('.foo').setAll('hidden', true);`

`querySelectorAll('.foo').setAll('value', 0);`

`querySelectorAll('.foo').setAll('dataset.owner', owner);`

`querySelectorAll('.foo').setAll('style.backgroundColor', '#f00');`

I am fully understanding of the fact that this isn't really a problem in javascript. Its easy to accomplish in numerous ways, but in general what are the downside of prototyping on native objects? You could even prototype short hand alias' for `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` I suppose.

I understand naming collisions could and eventually would become a problem. Any elegant way around that?

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only. You have several questions, and already a few answers, in there. What answer are you looking for?

Comment: I understand. I even managed to confuse myself with this post. Where am I again? I changed the title to express my main question.

Comment: In that case I'll have to close it as a duplicate though :-/ See also http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: Very nice article. Thanks.

Comment: "*Any elegant way around name collisions?*" - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-first-class-protocols (although they don't solve all problems with compatibility) or symbols.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was missing. Thanks.